# Is it possible to distribute threads in Thread Pool over nodes of GlassFish 3.1.1 cluster?

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish, threadpool, java-ee-6, distributed-computing

I want to distribute threads in Thread Pool over nodes of GlassFish 3.1.1 cluster.
Is it possible ?
If not, how I can use GlassFish cluster for distributed execution of threads ?

Thanks

Comment: This is typically done using JMS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose it depends on the nature of your application. The way we handle this is to push the thread logic down into an MDB. From there you can control how many MDB's run on each node in the cluster using the bean pool size.